# Simple slide down panel on hover and slide up on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my website i need to create a menu with linkbuttons which on hover slide down additional linkbuttons.

A smooth Slide Down/Up panel which slides down when i hover the linkbutton and slides up when the mouse is not the linkbutton or the content in slided panel

The code is working i dont have errors but when i hover the linkbutton the sliding panel just goes up and down like dancing without moving my mouse and when i try to reach the content inside it sometimes it closes sometimes not.

Checked some google and find the same solution as mine i guess is something in my CSS

Jquery:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nav1").mouseover(function() {
     $("#nav1extender").slideDown("slow");
   });
   $("#nav1").mouseout(function() {
     $("#nav1extender").slideUp("slow");
   });
 });
```

```css
.navigator {
  position: fixed !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333333;
  z-index: 1;
}
.NavButton {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  text-anchor: middle;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
}
.container {
  width: 99vw;
  height: 220vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="container" CssClass="Container">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="navigator" CssClass="navigator">

      <div style="position:relative;top:10vh;">

        <div id="nav1" style="position:relative;">
          <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="NavButton1" CssClass="NavButton" OnClick="NavButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
          <div id="nav1extender" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100px;display:none;background-color:#333333;z-index:2;top:3px;">
            asd
            <br />asd
            <br />asd
            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery hover method:

```
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);
```

this method will handle both mouseover and mouseout.

So I'd rewrite your code this way:

```
$( "#nav1" ).hover(
  function() {
    $("#nav1extender").slideDown("slow");
  }, function() {
    $("#nav1extender").slideUp("slow");
  }
);
```

This code will trigger slideUp as a callback of slideDown and should fix your issue

Comment: same problem and also to add additional problem the text inside the LinkButton which i must hover disapears after slide down strange..

Comment: http://hotelmontecristobg.azurewebsites.net/ this is the website check Хотел , Настаняване buttons

Comment: on Настаняване works as expected. what else do you want it to do?

Comment: well try to reach the content inside it and it slide up and again slides down and again 3 4 times atleast at my browser chrome

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue on safari and firefox

Comment: just installd firefox and its dancing there too strange thing